# mysqli_info() equivalent for PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to retrieve information like:

```
Records: 88 Duplicates: 12 Warnings: 2
```

When performing a batch insert with PDO?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [current PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src), the underlying [C API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/include_2mysql_8h.html#a6bf5a1bc75e654a767d76b4a7cde7a2c) [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-info.html) (related to the functionality in question) appears to be [`mysql_info()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d8ede80c7a92ca1f30592a91ae4afc80cf373e60/ext/mysqli/mysqli_api.c#L1478).

While this function appears to be [called in the source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d8ede80c7a92ca1f30592a91ae4afc80cf373e60/ext/mysqli/mysqli_api.c#L1478) within the PHP function [`mysqli_info`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d8ede80c7a92ca1f30592a91ae4afc80cf373e60/ext/mysqli/mysqli_api.c#L1478), as expected, this low-level function call is not currently found in the [available PDO source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mysql_info). The only places where the low-level [`mysql_info()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d8ede80c7a92ca1f30592a91ae4afc80cf373e60/ext/mysqli/mysqli_api.c#L1478) function is currently called include the following sources: `ext/mysqlnd`, `ext/mysqli`, and `ext/opcache`.

As noted by helllomatt, and as shown by the current source code, there just doesn't seem to be a current equivalent for the `mysqli_info` functionality at this time. If you really need this information, `mysqli_info` might be your main PHP-based option for now.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't an as detailed equivalent in PHP.  If you don't mind not knowing the specifics, [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) will tell you the affected rows of a query.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [PDO Rowcount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) to get the number of rows that were updated in by the last statement.

You can also directly get the number of records through using [Exec](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) - though only for non-select queries.

From the docs:

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('odbc:sample', 'db2inst1', 'ibmdb2');

/* Delete all rows from the FRUIT table */
$count = $dbh->exec("DELETE FROM fruit WHERE colour = 'red'");

/* Return number of rows that were deleted */
print("Deleted $count rows.\n");
?>
```

The above example will output:

> Deleted 1 rows.